# Regarding G729 integration in pjsip

Tags: android, c++, codec, pjsip, csip-simple

I am querying on this because I am not a C expert .See if any one who has worked around it could help.I am integrating g729 in pjsip lib and I got g729 codec files  from [here](http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CSipSimple/jni/g729/).Here are I steps I have followed :

First I have registered g729 in 'pjmedia/src/pjmedia-codec/audio_codecs.c' by putting this

```
#if PJMEDIA_HAS_G729_CODEC
    /* Register G729 */
    status = pjmedia_codec_g729_init(endpt);
    if (status != PJ_SUCCESS){

    return status;
     }
#endif
```

Now I have two files 'pj_g729.c' and 'pj_g729.h' that I have to copy in pjsip lib as per my knowledge.
So I have copied 'pj_g729.c' in 'pjmedia/src/pjmedia-codec'
& 'pj_g729.h' in '/root/pjsip/trunk_2_allloweversionsuccess_and_widssl_g729/pjmedia/include/pjmedia-codec'.

After doing this I am running make it is giving error :' undefined reference at  status = pjmedia_codec_g729_init(endpt);'.

Also I have doubt about 'PJMEDIA_HAS_G729_CODEC' as I haven't find  this variable declared in library.So do I have to declare it ??I am struggling over it for a long time.Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

> you can follow the steps as how g7221 added in pjsip.Find out the files in which g722 mentioned and add extra lines for g729 codec too.You can paste g729.a file in thirtparty library of pjsip.

Answer (score 1):

From the fact that the compiler sees the line with the error, it follows that `PJMEDIA_HAS_G729_CODEC` is in fact defined somewhere. Otherwise the line would have been skipped outright.

The problem is that in C, header files must be `#include`d to declare functions. This connects two source files. Here `audio_codecs.c` and `pj_g729.c` should both include `pj_g729.h`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include pj_g729.h into pjmedia-codec.h .

```
#include <pjmedia-codec/pj_g729.h>
```

This will include g729 header file into pjmedia-codec.h header  and will avoid the error of undefined reference at status = pjmedia_codec_g729_init(endpt);'.